# ionic cordova build android failed to build apk

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
>An error occurred while build android 

>Problem to build ionic cordova build android
>What went wrong:
>Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

>Try:
>Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug >option to get more log output.
```

> use native library are Google Map,Geolocation,Reverse Geocode,Facebook native

Answer (score 0):

Inside your plugins folder inside each plugin folder there wil be an xml file named plugin.xml

in these files find "com.android.support:support-v4:+" and change to 27.+

after that remove and add the platform with the following commands

```
    ionic cordova platform remove android
```

and

```
    ionic cordova platform add android
```

this will fix the issue